How to install ParaSCIP or FiberSCIP on a Windows64?
I want to increase the solving speed of an Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming (MIQP) optimization problem that I solve via SCIP solver.
I have tried to play with some SCIP parameters without any results:
opt.options['limits/gap'] = 0.05  # solving stops, if the relative gap = |primal - dual|/MIN(|dual|,|primal|) is below the given value, the gap is 'Infinity', if primal and dual bound have opposite signs # [type: real, advanced: FALSE, range: [0,1.79769313486232e+308], default: 0]
opt.options['parallel/minnthreads'] = 8 # the minimum number of threads used during parallel solve # [type: int, advanced: FALSE, range: [0,64], default: 1]
opt.options['parallel/maxnthreads'] = 32 # the maximum number of threads used during parallel solve # [type: int, advanced: FALSE, range: [0,64], default: 8]
I discovered the existance of ParaSCIP or FiberSCIP that allow SCIP solver parallelization but I wasn't able to install them and neither understand if they work in Windows. Any Suggestion or guide for installation and setup of ParaSCIP or FiberSCIP?
